# Prove an inequality $\ln(1-1/x)<2/(1-2x)$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I need some help to prove this inequality:

$$\ln(1-1/x) < \frac{2}{1-2x}$$
with
$$x > 1$$

I did plot the curve of $\ln(1-1/x)-2/(1-2x)$ and it's always in minus.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: consider the function $f(x)=\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)-\frac{2}{1-2x}$. Take derivative, check monotonicity etc.

Comment: When you say $\ln(1-1/x)-\frac 2{1-2x}$: "it's always in minus" indicates that in fact, $\ln(1 - 1/x)< \frac 2{1-2x}$.

Comment: When $a\lt b$, we know that $a-b \lt 0$, and $b-a>0$,

Comment: Thx for your tips.

Comment: @amWhy: i was not sure for all x > 1. with the derivative method, it looks clear for me now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=\ln(1-1/x)-\frac{2}{1-2x} \implies f'(x)=\frac{1}{x(x-1)(1-2x)^2}>0, if ~ x>1.$$ So $f(x)$ is an increasing function for $x>1 \implies f(x)<f(\infty) \implies f(x)<0$, and hence the result.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just forgot the way somehow. :)